# How to handle performance issue of update query inside of the SQL stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I created a sql query for update a table but it has a performance problem. From my asp.net platform will have timeout from sql database when I call below update from stored procedure. Can you help me to make it more faster and help db timeout problem?

```
    UPDATE e SET e.X=tablo.X,E.Y=ISNULL(tablo.Y,0),e.V=tablo.V,e.ADRES=tablo.ADRES,e.A=tablo.A
FROM tbltabloor e 
JOIN tablo_NOT tablo ON e.Z=tablo.Z AND E.T=convert(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(8),tablo.T,112)) AND E.U=tablo.U
WHERE NOT  exists (select * from tablo_NOT t where t.Z =e.Z AND E.T=convert(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(8),t.T,112)) AND  E.U=t.U 
AND E.X=t.X AND ISNULL(t.Y,0)=ISNULL(E.Y,0) AND E.V=t.V AND E.ADRES=t.ADRES
)
```

Comment: First step in optimising is to run it in SSMS, press CTRL-L and observe the query plan. It will suggest indexes that may help.

Comment: Issue could be anywhere really - it depends on the size of the tables, indexes etc - show your query plan!

Comment: Using `CONVERT` in the `ON` and `WHERE` clauses limits the ability of th optimizer to use indexes. A indexed computed column with the date extracted from the `DATETIME` might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look for any missing applicable indexes here using this:

```
SELECT 
statement AS [database.scheme.table],
column_id , column_name, column_usage, 
migs.user_seeks, migs.user_scans, 
migs.last_user_seek, migs.avg_total_user_cost,
migs.avg_user_impact
FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_details AS mid
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_db_missing_index_columns (mid.index_handle)
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups AS mig 
ON mig.index_handle = mid.index_handle
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats  AS migs 
ON mig.index_group_handle=migs.group_handle
ORDER BY mig.index_group_handle, mig.index_handle, column_id
```

Read more about this here [Missing Index Help](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2009/identify-missing-indexes-using-sql-server-dmvs/)

Also, try to remove the convert date stuff if at all possible from your where clause as that will definitely slow your query down.

Answer (score 2):

```
Did you create indexes on all join fields between tables? 
To accelerate processing without changing the structure of your current query, you must create these indexes.
Note that for fields calculated as _convert (datetime, CONVERT (varchar (8), tablo.T, 112))_, you must create function based index and here is a useful link that can help you: 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168213/function-based-indexes-in-sql-server][1].
Normally with this, executing your query will not result in a timeout.

hope this can help.
```