# TSQL Select Statement With A More Specific LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have a column that contains an patient ID, this ID has the clinic suffix at the end:

```
[Client Number]
29848393Ch
```

I run an audit script to count these with the clinic suffix past to it:

```
SELECT        COUNT(Client.[Client Number]) AS Count
    FROM            Client where [client number] like N'%' + @suffix
```

We are now moving to a three digit suffix which has caused issues with the query.

```
[Client Number]
29848393QCh
```

Is there a way to select a count passing the suffix and have it strictly return only results that contain the Ch and not QCh?

Comment: `where right([client number],2) = 'Ch'`  or you could setup a [computed column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx) similar to [function based index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168213/function-based-indexes-in-sql-server) and use the right 2 characters and limit by it.  From a performance standpoint the computed column using a right for 2 characters seems like the way to go.  Perhaps one for 2 and one for 3...

Comment: I think you should use RIGHT() not like -- should be faster, need me to post code?

Comment: Just saw xQbert's comment -- he is right.  You can also set up an index on RIGHT(x,2) on some platforms.

Comment: I think we would also need to do a check to ensure the 3rd most character from the right isn't a 'Q'; but I'm not sure if it's always Q or possibly some other value.  Note the computed column could be NULL when there is a Q in the 3rd character from right. again, the context isn't clear enough which is why this is a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write this way:

```
SELECT        COUNT(Client.[Client Number]) AS Count
FROM          Client 
WHERE [client number] like N'%[^Q]' + @suffix
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT        COUNT(Client.[Client Number]) AS Count
FROM          Client 
WHERE [client number] like N'%[^'+ @new_letter + ']' + @suffix
```

--@new_letter here could be your new added letter.

Comment: Problem is there is over 300 clinic suffix. I need to be able to pass @suffix and have it return a count.

Comment: Cool, can you explain what [^Q] is doing?

Comment: just saying that not a 'Q' at that position

Comment: If it helps, could you please accept the answer? Thank you.

Comment: Is there not a more dynamic way to do it? My problem is I might not know when they add another suffix. So one day I could be checking for clinic 'Fm' and it will work until they add a new clinic with suffix 'PFm'

Comment: I just edit it, check this out, feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: @Hogan You are right, if he already used variable, exact match with string function is definitely a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it. I don't know the size of the dataset, but you could try both ways and see which one performs better.

```
SELECT  COUNT(Client.[Client Number]) AS [Count]
FROM Client
WHERE Client.[Client Number] LIKE '%Ch%'
EXCEPT
SELECT *
FROM Client
WHERE Client.[Client Number] LIKE '%QCh%'
```

EDIT: With your replace solution you could do something like this that finds the first non numeric character and returns your suffix.

```
SUBSTRING(clientID, PATINDEX('%[a-z]%', Client.[Client Number]), LEN(Client.[Client Number]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks at the third index from the right... if it's a number then it meets the condition and if it isn't a number, then it doesn't. Thus, any number of characters that are added (i.e. anything with more than 2 characters on the end) won't be returned.

`where substring([client number],len([client number]) - 2,1) like '[0-9]'`

then, pair that with your suffix filter...

```
where 
   substring([client number],len([client number]) - 2,1) like '[0-9]'
   and [client number] like N'%' + @suffix
```

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for all the suggestions everyone, unfortunately nothing was flexible enough, I would need to search for a suffix without knowing if there was a clashing suffix plus sometimes I would need to look for a three lettered suffix.

I decided to go with a replace statement, I've tested for speed and it had a marginal affect.

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE ([client number], '0', ''),'1', ''),'2', ''),'3', ''),'4', ''),'5', ''),'6', ''),'7', ''),'8', ''),'9', '')  = @suffix
```

Might not be the perfect solution but it solves my problem and remains flexible enough for any suffix passed.

Comment: This is horrible.