# Is it possible to create a non clustered index on column length or any sql function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've searched over this website and I've looked over similar questions and i did not find the answer, I am sure it is somewhere but i did not find it, my problem is, i have a table called Maps, this tables contains millions and millions of rows and this table got indexes : a ClusteredIndex on **imagename** column and a NonClusteredIndex on **imagename** column and **downloaded** column,

The following query takes 0s to execute :

```
SELECT top 100 imagename 
from [maps] 
where imagename='SomeExistingImageName' 
and downloaded is null
```

*Result ->100rows*

Also, this following query takes 0s to execute :

```
SELECT top 100 imagename 
from [maps] 
where imagename='SomeRandomNameThatDoesNotExistOnMyDatabase' 
and donwloaded is null
```

*Result ->0rows*

But when i try to run this following query, it takes 02min08s to execute:

```
SELECT top 100 imagename 
from [maps] 
where LEN(imagename)=10
and downloaded is null
```

*Result -> 0rows (because there is no such imagename that fulfills those conditions)*

Another example, when I change 10 to 17 it takes 0s to execute :

```
SELECT top 100 imagename 
from [maps] 
where LEN(imagename)=17
and downloaded is null
```

*Result ->100rows*

My question is what it is the best way to improve the performance of this kind of query (query with column length) ? Is it possible to create another NonClusteredIndex on LEN(imagename) ? if the answer is YES which columns should be involved ?

PS : my table contains over 500M entries

Comment: Are you looking for [Function-based indexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168213/function-based-indexes-in-sql-server)?

Comment: I think you could probably add a computed column to keep the length of the imagename and set an index to the computed column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use virtual column

```
alter table [maps] add len_imagename as (len(imagename))
create index maps_ix_len_imagename on [maps] (len_imagename)
```

---

Demo

```
;with t(i) as (select 1 union all select i+1 from t where i<10)
select  replicate('x',rand(cast(newid() as varbinary))*1000)    AS i
into    #t
from    t t0,t t1,t t2,t t3,t t4,t t5,t t6
option  (maxrecursion 0)

alter table #t add len_i as (len(i))

create index #t_ix_len_i on #t (len_i)

select count(*) from #t where len_i between 99 and 101
```

[image]

Comment: My thoughts exactly. took me too long to test :-)

Comment: this new index is going to be applied only on len_imagename ? imagename and downloaded column should not be involved in this new index ?

Comment: I would either make it a filtered index - `create index maps_ix_len_imagename on [maps] (len_imagename) where downloaded is null;`, or have `downloaded` as a non key column - `create index maps_ix_len_imagename on [maps] (len_imagename) include(downloaded);` to avoid a key lookup.

Comment: Just demonstrating the concept haven't passed the topic :-)

Comment: @GarethD should I also include the imagename ? or is it worthless ?

Comment: There is no need, since this is the clustering key it is stored within the nonclustered index anyway as a pointer to the right place within the clustered index

Comment: ok thank you, last question : you suggested two indexes which one you think is the best ( a small why if i can ask :) ) Thank you in advance

Comment: Which one is best depends on what queries you are running. The filtered index is smaller and less overhead to maintain but less versatile, so it depends on your needs; if like your question, all your queries exclude non null records with `and downloaded is null`, then the filtered index will suffice, if you have more diverse queries then including `downloaded` as either a key or non-key column. There is no right or wrong choice here, just a more or less suitable one, but only you would know which is which.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me :

```
alter table [maps] add len_imagename as (len(imagename));
create index [maps] on [maps] (len_imagename) include([downloaded]);
```

The execution time now of the following query is 0s :

```
SELECT top 100 imagename 
from [maps] 
where LEN(imagename)=10
and downloaded is null
```