# How to avoid function in the left field side of the predicate?

Tags: sql, t-sql, query-optimization

As per [this](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/identifying-and-solving-index-scan-problems/) article,

**First Rule: You can’t use a function in the left side (the field side) of the predicate.**

I have a table with a field TOTAL_ARREARS declared as

```
[TOTAL_ARREARS] [nvarchar](50) NULL
```

and I cannot change that.

Now the query is a simple one

```
select Id,name
from tbl
where CAST(TOTAL_ARREARS AS FLOAT)> 0
```

The execution plan shows
[image]

How can I apply the First Rule of the article here (avoiding function on the left)?

### Edit

I tried with `WHERE TOTAL_ARREARS NOT IN('0.000','.000')` that though solved but not happy with the solution.

Is there anything better?

Comment: What is the datatype of `TOTAL_ARREARS`

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`.

Comment: An indexed persisted computed column. Does something smell bad here?

Answer (score 0):

First of the table design should be looked into where we are using a varchar column to store numeric values.

In case of Oracle database you can always explore the option of function based index to get around of these kind of issues. In case of function based indexes the index key will be based on functions rather than the actual column value. It will only be used when you use the same **exactly** the same string(including case of letters) in the predicate.

In case of databases where function based index is not available you can consider creating an additional column as mentioned in the following post for sql server.

[Function-based indexes in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168213/function-based-indexes-in-sql-server)