# Oracle to SQL Server database migration issues

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-migration

I'm trying to convert an Oracle databse Schema into a SQL Server schema using the tool SQL Server Migration Assistant by Microsoft. The conversion seems to work pretty well but I still get two error messages:

-02SS0269: Index 'DB.MY_TABLE.MY_INDEX' is functional and cannot be converted.

-O2SS0472: Conversion of 'MY_USER_DEFINED_TYPE' failed because collection type is not supported.

I would like to know if I can ignore these error messages and consider that the SQL database that I obtain matches the original Oracle database in terms of database structure (tables, columns, data...).

I also would like to know what solutions/workaround I can apply to solve those two migration issues and get an SQL Server db that matches the original Oracle one.

Comment: Not if you need the index or use the type.

Comment: Ok, and what should I normally do in this case, assuming that I'm gonna need the index and use the type, is there a common procedure to follow or a workaround to apply?

Comment: For a replacement for function based indexes, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168213/function-based-indexes-in-sql-server - in short, you create a function-based column in the table, then index it.

Comment: Ok, thanks @ammoQ , but anyway the SQL Server database I obtained will worked fine (ignoring the two error messages) right?

Comment: The database will probably work fine, but your application maybe not.