# Query to update a column in a table from another table without creating a procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables. table 1 is called filenames, table 2 is called grants.
filenames table has column called folder_name, example of a folder_name value is "E:/x/y/z/10689/t/y/c". 10689 is the grant id. I would like to update a column called "grant_id" in filenames table from grants table. I would like to do this without creating cursors and procedure. A view will even do. how is this possible using the "like" command and parsing the grant id from folder_name and checking it against grants table. This is one to many relationship ... one grant (10689 - folder basically) can have multiple files and I need to map all folder_name values with the same grant id if it contains 10689. is there a way to do this without a writing cursor and procedure?

I'm new to SQL Server so bear with me. Basically, can I write my a sql query instead of writing a procedure like below.

```
DECLARE @grant_id AS INT;
DECLARE @grant_number AS varchar(100);

declare cursor_grants cursor for
    select grant_id, grant_number
    from grant_info
    where grant_id = 10689;


open cursor_grants;

fetch next from cursor_grants into @grant_id, @grant_number;
while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
        update filenames
        set log_num = @grant_number, grant_id = @grant_id
        where location like '%/'+cast(@grant_id as varchar)+'/%';

        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_grants INTO @grant_id, @grant_number;
    end;

CLOSE cursor_grants;
DEALLOCATE cursor_grants;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use the Like Operator in the Table Join**

The underlying premise with this problem is that the foreign key in the folder name table will often times need to be updated and that there is a 1 to many relationship betweeen the grants and folder name tables.

Because of this, I would join the folder name table with the grant table using the like operator for this scenario and then more broadly (as your requirement dictates) otherwise we would not update folder name records which meet this match criteria.

```
UPDATE fname
SET
    fname.grant_id = grnt.grant_id
FROM
         filenames fname
    JOIN grants grnt ON fname.folder_name LIKE '%/' + CAST(grnt.grant_id AS VARCHAR) + '/%'
WHERE
        1 = 1
    -----example scenario-----
    AND grnt.grant_id = 10689;
```

Comment: thanks ... is there a way to update a million records fast using this query ...its taking over 15 minutes and still running. ...

Comment: Hi @AJR, yes, the join is inherently painful from a performance perspective. If you were going to issue a command like this often against a large number of records, you might consider a variation of SQL Server's version of a  function based index (see this post,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168213/function-based-indexes-in-sql-server ).

Comment: @AJR . . . Updating a million records is going to take a while.  Often, it is better to just reconstruct the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use update with join

```
update f set f.grant_id=g.grant_id
from filenames f inner join grants g on f.grant_id=g.grant_id
where   folder_name like '%/10689/%'
```

Comment: Hi Fahmi - thanks for reply. Is there a way to grab the grant id, add it as an additional column to the select instead of updating the table. and since I need to this for all grants ... I'm assuming there has to be a loop to do this?

Comment: @AJR, could you please add some sample data and your desired output in a tabular format - then it would be easy to understand to answer your question

Comment: Done .... I added the code ... I am trying to change code above to sql query instead of a procedure or adding it in a procedure. is it possible? I would like to create a view is possible.

Comment: @AJR, view is just a select statement. You cannot have UPDATE queries in view. You need to have this UPDATE logic as an ad-hoc statement or as part of PROCEDURE